# Describing something is on something

Tags: prepositions

If A applies sunscreen on the face, and I kisses A’s cheek, why does “my lips is on A’s cheek” make sense even though there is sunscreen between my lips and A’s cheek.

I’m sorry for asking a basic question because there are no alternatives of “on” in my native language.

Comment: (It's _I kiss_ and _My lips are_.) If you touch a part of a person's body, the fact that they have recently applied some substance to their skin makes no difference to the way the action is described.

Comment: It's more than that: _he put his hand on her arm_ doesn't tell us whether or not she is wearing a garment with sleeves, or whether or not he is wearing gloves.

Comment: It's because English is concerned with where the kiss lands, and that is of primary concern because it's someone else's body, outside of yourself. The fact that you get sunscreen on your lips while kissing A is a detail.

Comment: And if you are wearing lipstick your lips are still on their cheek.